# Caching full path of an object item and then using it for assignation doesn't work

Tags: javascript, variables, object, caching

I have an object and each time the function runs I want to switch the value of an item inside. If I cache the full path inside the var, it does not work, only if I leave out the item and cache the path without it, it works as I expect.

```
var foo1 = function (identifier) { // Does not work
  var counting = some.object.with[identifier].counting;
  counting = (!counting) ? "bar" : false; // Switch values
};

var foo2 = function (identifier) { // Work!
  var identifier = some.object.with[identifier];
  identifier.counting = (!identifier.counting) ? "bar" : false;
};
```

Any ideas why?

Comment: This is a reference (or scope) problem. If you access `counting` you just get the value. In the second code you are actually getting the reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In example one, you are storing a primitive property in a variable and then replacing only the value of that local variable.

In example two, you are storing a reference to an object and then updating a property on that object.

Answer (score 1):

In the first example you're grabbing the value, rather than the reference to the object's field, so effectively you're only changing a variable, rather than the object's field itself.

So, a simplistic example would be:

```
var o = {a:1, b:2},
    v = o.a;
console.log(v); //outputs 1
v = 3;
console.log(v); //outputs 3
console.log(o); //outputs {a:1, b:2} - since o wasn't changed directly
```

Also, checking if the value is falsey doesn't strike me as good practice, unless you intended to account for `undefined`. Perhaps it's better to cast to boolean with `!!counting` ?

Answer (score 0):

This is because in the second case you are assigning a reference to an object to the `identifier` variable, therefore any change you make will change the object being referenced. The scope of the referenced object is presumably outside of the function `foo2` and therefore the object and any change made continues to exists between calls.